# How to prove that the following function is increasing?

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I'm trying to prove that the function

$f(t)=t\ln(1+\frac{k}{t})$; with $k\geq 0$

is increasing for $t>0$. I calculated the derivative and obtained

$f'(t)=\ln(1+\frac{k}{t})-\frac{k}{t+k}$,

but I don't know how to conclude that $f'(t)\geq0$ for $t>0$. Can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263) I showed using only the limit definition of the exponential function and Bernoulli's Inequality that the logarithm function satisfies the inequality
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\log(x)\ge \frac{x-1}{x}}\tag 1$$
>
> for $x>0$.

---

Applying $(1)$, we see that

$$\begin{align}
f'(t)&=\log\left(1+\frac kt\right)-\frac{k}{t+k}\\\\
&\ge \frac{k}{t+k}-\frac{k}{t+k}\\\\
&=0\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: This is really good answer!

Comment: @maxpayne Thank you.  Much appreciative.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very detailed. Seriously, thank you very much.

Comment: @JuanDavidSamboní You're welcome!  It was my pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 2):

Find $f''(t)$

$$f''(t) = -\dfrac{k^2}{t(k+t)^2}$$

We see, $f''t < 0$ for $t > 0$. So $f'(t)$ is decreasing for $t > 0$

Also, the limit of $t \to \infty$ of $f'(t)$ is $0$:

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}f'(t) = \ln1 = 0$$

So, $f'(t)$ cannot be $< 0$ and must be $> 0$ for any finite $x$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
f'(t)&=\ln\left(1+\frac{k}{t}\right)-\frac{k}{t+k}\\\\
&=\int_1^{1+\frac{k}{t}}\frac{1}{x}\;dx- \frac{k}{t+k}\\\\
&\geq \int_1^{1+\frac{k}{t}}\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{t}}\;dx- \frac{k}{t+k}\\\\
&=\frac{t}{t+k}\frac{k}{t}-\frac{k}{t+k}\\\\
&=0
\end{align}